# Chrome on host Windows 8.1 can't connect to guest running Ubuntu 14.04 with apache

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, google-chrome

I'm using VirtualBox on my Windows 8.1 pc to host a Ubuntu Server 14.04 guest that runs Apache as a development web server.

I'm using Bridged Adapter in VirtualBox.

I have a few vhost on Apache and I can access all of them using Firefox or IE from the host. But I can't access it using Chrome.

Chrome gives me the following:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Google Chrome's connection attempt to cooksfromhome.localhost was
rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be
properly configured.

[...]
```

From what I understand, my Apache config should be okay because I can access it without problem with Firefox and IE... It looks as if Chrome can access my VirtualBox, but Apache refuses the connection... Any idea why I have this problem and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Chrome ignores all entries in the host file that tries to send any website with .localhost to an IP that is not the computer's local address.
(https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489973)

So I modified my Apache vhost in my Ubuntu VirtualBox from

```
ServerName mysite.localhost
```

to

```
ServerName mysite.local.host
```

(And I modified my host file accordingly) And now it's working!

Note that the ServerName could be whatever you want, as long as it doesn't end with .localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Go to the **LAN settings** (in Chrome: *Tools → Options → Under the hood → Change Proxy setting → LAN Setting*)
- Tick the checkbox *"Bypass proxy server for local address"*

Comment: For me to be able to tick the checkbox, I have to tick "Use a proxy server for your LAN" first. That first checkbox unblock an address input, a port input (default to 80) and an "Advanced" button. I ticked both checkbox, left the address input empty and I still have the same issue.

Comment: I have been looking for this exact fix for weeks now - thank you :)